# How do I make a file executale?

Tags: permissions

It's me again. How would I go about changing a file's permissions to make it executable? I'm guessing the command starts with sudo, but after that I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo chmod +x /path/to/file`.

Comment: It says "+x: command not found."

Comment: Impossible. You did something wrong, +x is just a parameter.

Comment: Since I'm new to Linux, it's quite possible I did something wrong.

Comment: Try typing the command word by word and then run it again.

Comment: Oh. I left out "chmod".

Comment: Did it work properly?

Comment: No, it didn't. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Sudo isn't really required in all cases. If you are the owner of the file, you can make it executable without Sudo

Answer (score 0):

Run `ls -l /path/to/file`.  This will show you the current mode for the file.  You will get something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 owner  group  102 Apr  8 16:40 GoToMeeting (2553).app
```

The `drwxr-xr-x` portion is what you are interested in.  You may also be interested in the permissions on one or more of the parent directories.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to get programs like Steam to run. To do that, it seems I need to get permission.

Comment: What are any error messages you get?

Comment: No error message; it just won't run.

Comment: Is there a way of finding out whether a program is installed using the command prompt?

Comment: Yes. There are several ways to find things.  I use locate often: `locate steam`, for instance.  Trying to use a manual, info, or help page can also be useful - `man steam` or `help steam` or `info steam`.  If installed you will get a match.

locate might be the easiest for you.  it will find most anything in your system with that matches "steam"

Comment: So with all that said, if I have it successfully installed, which file would run the Steam client?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Valve Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve), and assuming everything is properly installed:

> ## Running Steam
>
> A Steam icon should now be present in the Unity Launcher and possibly
> on your desktop -- depending on your Desktop Environment.
> Alternatively, click on the Ubuntu icon in the upper left corner and
> search for steam in the Dash.
>
> Log in via the Steam client and in the Store section look for a Linux
> tab to see the native titles available for purchase or install.
>
> The Steam for Linux official Hub is worth visiting for future
> announcements and other information, as well as active discussion
> about the client and games.

At this point, I would suggest visiting [the Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve), since it includes instructions and links for everything from requirements, to dependencies, to installation, to execution.